# How to create a URL that Spring Data JPA can parse to include sort with nulls_first?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA to query a repository and to sort the results, some of them include nulls and I would like to put them on top when sorting in ascending mode.

At the moment I am able to do it from the backend using this,

```
private Sort addNullsFirstToSorting(final Pageable page){
    final List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    final Sort sort = page.getSort();
    sort.get().forEach(order->{
            if(order.getProperty().equals("specificProperty")){
                orders.add(order.nullsFirst());
            }else{
                orders.add(order);
            }
    });
    return Sort.by(orders);
}
```

However, I would prefer to know how I can create a URL with the necessary parameters so that JPA is able to parse and include the NULLS_FIRST automatically, making the above method not needed.

Comment: `NULLS_FIRST` and `NULLS_LAST` is not supported by JPA. I guess a workaround would be additional fields that contain a 0 if the corresponding field is null and 1 other wise an use those for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate you can fix it by using hibernate property `hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering`

In your Spring (Boot) application.yml:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering: first
            # or for last: hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering: last
```